# Is $O(k)\times O(n-k)$ closed in $SO(n)$?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, orthogonal-matrices, homogeneous-spaces

Let $O(m)$ denote the group of orthogonal matrices under multiplication, and let $SO(m)$ be the special orthogonal group over $\mathbb{R}$. Let 
\begin{equation*}
(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n):=\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0\\
0 & C
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \mid B\in O( k) ,\ C\in O( n-k) ,\ \det( B)\det( C) =1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

I want to prove/disprove $O(k)\times O(n-k)$, $k=1,\dots,n-1$ is closed in $SO(n)$.

I do not really know how.

Even for $k=1$, I am not too sure. For $k=1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
b & 0\\
0 & C
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \mid b\in O( 1) ,\ C\in O( n-1) ,\ b\det( C) =1\right\} =H_{1} \cup H_{-1} ,
\end{equation*}
where for $b=1,-1$ we let
\begin{equation*}
H_{b} :=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
b & 0\\
0 & C
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \mid \ C\in O( n-1) ,\ \det( C) =b\right\} .
\end{equation*}
I want to say this is essentially the union of $SO(n-1)$ and thus closed, but I am not really comfortable with seeing $SO(n-1)$ as a subset of $SO(n)$ incorporating the topological consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each orthogonal group is compact, $O(k)\times O(n-k)$ is compact and therefore a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. And your set is a closed subset of this one, because it's the set of thos elements whose determinant is $1$. Since $\det$ is continuous and $\{1\}$ is closed, this is again a closed set.

Comment: I see. Just to check:$(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n)=\det^{-1}(\{1\})$, i.e. it is the preimage of $\det:O(k)\times O(n-k)\to \{1\}$. Thus, $(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n)$ is closed in $O(k)\times O(n-k)$. But $O(k)\times O(n-k)$ is closed in the whole space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Thus, $(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n)$ is closed in  $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (cf., https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_in_Topological_Subspace). But $SO(n)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n)\subset SO(n)$. Thus $(O(k)\times O(n-k))\cap SO(n)$ is closed in $SO(n)$?

Comment: (The question I am asking in the comment above is if the above was the argument you used, but there wasn't enough room to put my intention of the comment, which I am typing here.)

Comment: @user41467 That's it, with this extra detail: $O(k)\times O(n-k)$ is closed because it's compact and it is compact because both $O(k)$ and $O(n-k)$ are compact.